# azure data factory - bring in filename from blob and use as variable for column name

Tags: azure-data-factory

using azure data factory I am trying to get the filename from blob, then adjust name, and add it as a column to output.

this is what I've done and it is not working.

can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
The value of property 'additionalColumns' is in unexpected type 'IList`1'.
```

[image: getmetadata]

[image: setvariable]

[image: copydata]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The above error is because you are providing the dynamic content expression of variable to the whole Additional columns dynamic content.

To create an additional column with a dynamic expression in copy activity source, you need to create a **new** column manually and then provide the dynamic content from the drop-down options.

[image]

You will get a dynamic content option from the drop-down list of `Value` field. Click on that and it will open dynamic editor where you need to provide your expression like above.

**Result:**

[image]

If the source file of copy activity and file in the Get meta data activity are different, then you can follow the above approach.

But if both are same files, that means if you want to get a file name of the same source file of copy activity, **there is no need to use Get meta data activity to get the file name**. you can use a direct option `$$FILENAME` in the `Value` drop-down options of copy activity **Additional columns**.

[image]

Comment: in copy data, source tab, I add additional column, name=filedate, then in value I put @activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName. then when i hit preview source, i get a popup. please provide actual value of the parameteres to preview data. at the bottom it says name=@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName. type string, then in value it wants me to put something.  do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, while previewing the data, it won't take the value dynamically from the previous activity or variable. Here, the value of `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName` is coming from executing get meta data activity and preview won't execute the pipeine. Preview data is only for checking whether the data is correct or wrong. To preview the data with additional column, if the additional column involves any dynamic content, you need to provide that value in that box. Its only for preview. When you debug pipeline, it will take the column dynamically and copied to the target like mine.

Comment: Just give your sample filename in that box and check whether preview is giving correct data or not. Debugging pipeline, will give that value from previous Get meta data activity output dynamicallu and it will give the expected results in the target location.